# List of files modified 1 hour before

Tags: linux, shell, unix

Hi I want a list of files modified within 60 minutes.

```
bash-3.2$ find . -mmin 60 -type f
find: bad option -mmin
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
bash-3.2$ /usr/xpg4/bin/find . -mmin 60 -type f                                                                                                                                                          
/usr/xpg4/bin/find: bad option -mmin
/usr/xpg4/bin/find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
bash-3.2$ 
utibbwdev1#uname -a
SunOS utibbwdev1 5.10 Generic_150400-13 sun4v sparc SUNW,T5240
```

I am getting the above error. My OS is sun version 5.10.

Comment: `find --version` could be a good thing.  Perhaps you are not using the proper find command.

Answer (score 3):

Find command can do that.

```
find .  -newermt "1 hour ago"
```

You can further filter it with `-type f`

Comment: bash-3.2$ find .  -newermt "1 hour ago"                                                                                                                                                                  
find: bad option -newermt
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
bash-3.2$

Comment: What is your `find` version? `find --version`

Comment: What is command for find version ? find --version not working

Comment: `find -v` or `find -V` or `find -version` etc. Check it in `find --help` output

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im, He has said he is using SunOS, on sparc.  He doesn't use GNU find.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using this command.

```
$ find . -mtime -1
```

where,

`.` is the search path

`-mtime` time parameter

`-1` list files modified in last 1 hours

also

```
$ find . -amin -60
```

`-amin` time parameter (minute wise)

`-60` list files modified in last 1 hours

Here is an output from my system:

[image]

Comment: bash-3.2$ find . -amin -60
    find: bad option -amin
    find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
    bash-3.2$

Comment: mtime 1 gives files older by 2 days. Not hour basis.

Answer (score 1):

As you are on **SunOS**, probably you are not using **GNU find**, so `-mmin` option is not allowed.  Try

```
find -mtime -1
```

to get files/dirs of modification time under (that's the meaning of the minus sign in front of the number) 1 hour from now.  GNU finds makes it possible to ask for times in minutes as an extension to normal find.

Also, the man page is very useful, but perhaps, if you have the **GNU findutils** package installed on your system, you have to do some `PATH` adjustements before to get the correct find program called.  Just look as GNU utils normally get installed under /opt/gnu directory and you'll need to put that directory in the PATH **before** the normal bin dirs.  A good way to check this is to do

```
which find
```

that will tell you which find it is using and where in the filesystem it is located.  A common mistake is to put man pages first in the MANPATH environment variable, but last in the PATH variable, so you get the manpage from GNU findutils package but execute the standard system command.  find in SunOS comes from Berkeley Unix and is not related to GNU.

Comment: -rw-r-----   1 tibco    tibco    10517562 Nov 15 16:58 sbnbroker.log.4
-rw-r-----   1 tibco    tibco    10502623 Nov 17 09:24 sbnbroker.log.3
-rw-r-----   1 tibco    tibco    10603229 Nov 18 08:07 sbnbroker.log.2
-rw-r-----   1 tibco    tibco    10507088 Nov 18 13:15 sbnbroker.log.1
-rw-r-----   1 tibco    tibco    9969653 Nov 19 09:06 sbnbroker.log
bash-3.2$ find . -mtime -1
.
./sbnbroker.log
./sbnbroker.log.1
bash-3.2$

Comment: bash-3.2$ which find
/bin/find
bash-3.2$ 
There is no opt/gnu directory

Comment: so perhaps you need to install GNU find.  your find is not the GNU one.

Comment: try http://unixpackages.com/packages/solaris-2-5-sparc#findutils to download and install GNU findutils packages. It installs in /usr/local, as that page says.

Answer (score 1):

For a POSIX compatible method you can make a temporary file with [`touch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html), using the time from [`date`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html), after subtracting one hour with [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html), and use [`find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)'s [`-newer` operand](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_05) to compare files with the temporary file.

```
TIME=`date "+%Y %m %d %H %M" | awk '
    BEGIN{split("31 28 31 30 31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31",M)}
    {
        if ($4 == 0) { # hour underflow
            if ($3 == 1) { # day underflow
                if ($2 == 1) { # month underflow
                    $1--;
                    $2 = 12;
                } else $2--;
                if ($1 % 4 == 0 && $2 == 2) $3 = 29; # leap year
                else $3 = M[$2];
            } else $3--;
            $4 = 23;
        } else $4--;
        printf "%04u%02u%02u%02u%02u\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5;
    }'`
touch -t "$TIME" some-temporary-file
find . -type f -newer some-temporary-file
rm some-temporary-file
```

To get a temporary file name you can use a utility such as [`mktemp`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mktemp&sektion=1), you can specify a file, or you can append random numbers to a file name.

Quite a few versions of [`find`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&sektion=1) have the `-mmin` extension, or something like it.

```
find . -type f -mmin -60
```

Some versions of [`date`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=date&sektion=1) have a variable output.

```
FILE=`mktemp -t one-hour-ago-`
touch -t `date -v -1h +%Y%m%d%H%M` "$FILE"
find . -type f -newer "$FILE"
rm "$FILE"
```

And some versions of [`touch`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=touch&sektion=1) have adjustment flags.

```
FILE=`mktemp -t one-hour-ago-`
touch "$FILE"
touch -A -010000 "$FILE"
find . -type f -newer "$FILE"
rm "$FILE"
```