# using awk with arrays

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am using below commands for getting details for each channel. Instead of grep with channel name can we combine below commands into one. So for all channels it will provide total success and failure for each service. I have given expected output below for more clarity.

$2 is channel $11 is the service type, $12 is either S(success) or F(failure), and $14 is elapsed time.

```
grep 'EXSTAT|BNK' sample.log|/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F"|" '
          {a[$11]=1}
           $12=="S"{sc[$11]++;st[$11]+=$14}
           $12=="F"{fc[$11]++;ft[$11]+=$14}
           END{for(t in a){
               printf "%s,%u,",t,sc[t]+fc[t];
               if(sc[t])printf "%u,%g,",sc[t],st[t]/sc[t];else printf "0,0,";
               if(fc[t])printf "%u,%g\n",fc[t],ft[t]/fc[t];else print "0,0";
            }}'  
QCD,1,546,1,546,0,0
QASM,1,2460,1,2460,0,0
QBEND,1,247,1,247,0,0

grep 'EXSTAT|SBN' sample.log|/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F"|" '
          {a[$11]=1}
           $12=="S"{sc[$11]++;st[$11]+=$14}
           $12=="F"{fc[$11]++;ft[$11]+=$14}
           END{for(t in a){
               printf "%s,%u,",t,sc[t]+fc[t];
               if(sc[t])printf "%u,%g,",sc[t],st[t]/sc[t];else printf "0,0,";
               if(fc[t])printf "%u,%g\n",fc[t],ft[t]/fc[t];else print "0,0";
            }}'  
QASM,3,10202,3,3400.67,0,0
QBSD,4,674,4,168.5,0,0

Expected Output

BNK,QCD,1,1,546,0,0
BNK,QASM,1,1,2460,0,0
BNK,QBEND,1,1,247,0,0
MEM,QBATI,10,10,289.4,0,0
SBN,QASM,3,3,3400.67,0,0
SBN,QBSD,4,4,168.5,0,0 

bash-3.2$ grep 'EXSTAT|' sample.log|/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F"|" '
           {a[$11]=$2}
           $12=="S"{sc[$11]++;st[$11]+=$14}
           $12=="F"{fc[$11]++;ft[$11]+=$14}
           END{for(t in a){
               printf "%s,%s,%u,",a[t],t,sc[t]+fc[t];
               if(sc[t])printf "%u,%g,",sc[t],st[t]/sc[t];else printf "0,0,";
               if(fc[t])printf "%u,%g\n",fc[t],ft[t]/fc[t];else print "0,0";
           }}'
BNK,QCD,1,1,546,0,0
SBN,QBSD,4,4,168.5,0,0
MEM,QBATI,10,10,289.4,0,0
SBN,QASM,4,4,3165.5,0,0
BNK,QBEND,1,1,247,0,0
bash-3.2$
```

===========Log========

EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|24|11|07|53|403056|E582783758|QBEND|S|000|247
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|24|11|07|59|403057|E582783759|QASM|S|000|2460
EXSTAT|MEM|2014|11|24|11|08|00|403059|24112014110702|QBATI|S|000|310
EXSTAT|MEM|2014|11|24|11|09|00|403063|24112014110802|QBATI|S|000|278
EXSTAT|SBN|2014|11|24|11|09|36|403064|142802|QBSD|S|000|181
EXSTAT|MEM|2014|11|24|11|10|00|403065|24112014110902|QBATI|S|000|316
EXSTAT|MEM|2014|11|24|11|11|00|403066|24112014111002|QBATI|S|000|242
EXSTAT|MEM|2014|11|24|11|12|01|403067|24112014111102|QBATI|S|000|330
EXSTAT|MEM|2014|11|24|11|13|01|403068|24112014111202|QBATI|S|000|273
EXSTAT|SBN|2014|11|24|11|13|35|403069|15785|QASM|S|000|1572
EXSTAT|SBN|2014|11|24|11|13|56|403073|15786|QASM|S|000|3543
EXSTAT|MEM|2014|11|24|11|14|01|403074|24112014111302|QBATI|S|000|249
EXSTAT|SBN|2014|11|24|11|14|16|403075|15787|QASM|S|000|5087
EXSTAT|MEM|2014|11|24|11|15|00|403076|24112014111402|QBATI|S|000|347
EXSTAT|BNK|2014|11|24|11|15|52|403077|E582783764|QCD|S|000|546
EXSTAT|SBN|2014|11|24|11|15|53|403078|142806|QBSD|S|000|160
EXSTAT|MEM|2014|11|24|11|16|00|403079|24112014111502|QBATI|S|000|294
EXSTAT|SBN|2014|11|24|11|16|57|403080|142807|QBSD|S|000|170
EXSTAT|MEM|2014|11|24|11|17|00|403081|24112014111602|QBATI|S|000|255
EXSTAT|SBN|2014|11|24|11|17|42|403082|142808|QBSD|S|000|163

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the combined string `$2","$11` as the array index.

```
awk -F"|" '!/EXSTAT\|/{next}
           {t=$2","$11;a[t]=1}
           $12=="S"{sc[t]++;st[t]+=$14}
           $12=="F"{fc[t]++;ft[t]+=$14}
           END{for(t in a){
               printf "%s,%u,",t,sc[t]+fc[t];
               if(sc[t])printf "%u,%g,",sc[t],st[t]/sc[t];else printf "0,0,";
               if(fc[t])printf "%u,%g\n",fc[t],ft[t]/fc[t];else print "0,0";
           }}' sample.log
```

- `!/EXSTAT\|/{next}` skips any lines not containing `EXSTAT`, this replaces `grep "EXSTAT|"`.
- `{t=$2","$11;a[t]=$2}` sets the channel and service type in array `a`, separated by a comma.
- `$12=="S"{sc[t]++;st[t]+=$14}` `$12=="S"` checks for success. The remainder increments the success count `sc` and sums the success time `st`.
- `$12=="F"{fc[t]++;ft[t]+=$14}` `$12=="F"` checks for failure. The remainder increments the failure count `fc` and sums the failure time `ft`.
- `printf "%s,%u,",t,sc[t]+fc[t]` prints the output fields that are always present.
- `if(sc[t])printf "%u,%g,",sc[t],st[t]/sc[t];else printf "0,0,"` prints the success count and average time, guarding from a division by zero error.
- `if(fc[t])printf "%u,%g\n",fc[t],ft[t]/fc[t];else print "0,0"` prints the failure count and average time, guarding from a division by zero error.

Comment: Hi it is working fine.One more query. If I want to check for 2nd parameter EGP along with EXSTAT how to do it. EXSTAT|EGP|2014|09|21|12|02|31|1001|QSWR1236|QSWR|S|000|4385

Comment: @Guru You con use boolean [expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02) in [patterns](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_01). So you can add a second condition to the skipping line. `$1!="EXSTAT"||$2!=EGP{next}`

Comment: For some directories I am getting below error. /usr/xpg4/bin/awk: line 0 (NR=40945): Record too long (LIMIT: 19999 bytes)
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F"|" '$1!="EXSTAT"||$2!=EGP{next}\
           /\|F\|/{fc[$11]++;ft[$11]+=$14}\
           /\|S\|/{sc[$11]++;st[$11]+=$14}\
           END{for(t in sc){\
               printf "%s,%u,%u,%g,",t,sc[t]+fc[t],sc[t],st[t]/sc[t];\
               if(fc[t])printf "%u,%g\n",fc[t],ft[t]/fc[t];\
               else print "0,0"}}' $(find $ectpath -mtime 0 -type f). Any solution for this or records are too high.

Comment: @Guru You could try a different utility (`perl`, `C`, maybe replace filter line with a piped `grep` like the original), or a different version of `awk`. I had no problems getting `nawk` or `gawk` to read and write records longer than that. `nawk` is the default on _*BSD_ and `gawk` on most _Linux_ distributions, and _OS X_.

Comment: @Guru Perhaps your `find` is finding some binary files in it's search. If so narrowing it down might help. Another solution, found [here](http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/16511-record-too-long-awk.html), is to use `cut` to trim lines to a sane size before it gets to `awk`.

Comment: I am using $(find $ectpath -mtime 0 -type f) for getting files changed in last 24 hours. Is there any command for getting list of files in hourly basis. Like log files changed in last 1hour. I have tried $ find . -mtime -1 but its giving last 24 hour. bash-3.2$ find . -mmin 60 -type f
find: bad option -mmin
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
utibbwdev1#uname -a
SunOS utibbwdev1 5.10 Generic_150400-13 sun4v sparc SUNW,T5240 Help please.

Comment: @Guru I added an answer to your [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968159/).

Comment: Above command is working fine for service which has atleast one success but fails for services which are always failure. As the for loop done on sc which is success array. That is the reason TTPPY and QRCD is not appearing in output.

Comment: @Guru I changed the answer to print `SrvType,TotalCount,Success,SuccessTime,Failure,FailureTime`. In your question you specified `SuccessSrvType` and only gave examples with successful termination.

Comment: Thanks it is working fine.I have edited the question now. Please check whether we can acheive in one command.

Comment: QASM service type available for BNK as well as SBN. But its coming for SBN with total count 4. But BNK count is 1 and SBN count is 3.

Comment: @Guru The answer now give the correct output, that is if order is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks it is working fine. But is there a way if we want to alphabetically order based on $2(channel).

Comment: @Guru Pipe the output to [`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html).